# elif error en Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

Estoy creando un juego con pygame en el que uso una clase llamada
CreaSprites que hereda de pygame.sprite.Sprite. Para crear algo parecido a la sobreescritura del constructor uso las siguientes
instrucciones:

```
class CreaSprites(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, largo, alto):
        # Llama al constructor de la clase padre (Sprite)
       
        super().__init__()
       
        '''Los bloques de obstáculos son llamados a construir
        con tres parámetros, el primero de los cuales es un tupla
        de los tres componentes RGB del color'''
       
        if isinstance(color, tuple):
            # Crea una imagen del bloque y lo rellena de color.
            self.image = pygame.Surface([largo, alto])
            self.image.fill(color)

            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        '''En caso de que se llame al constructor con un primer parámetro de tipo pygame.Surface '''

        if isinstance(color, pygame.Surface):
            self.image = color
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Para llamar al constructor para que cree una imagen se hace:

```
imagen_gato = pygame.image.load("resources/icons/gato.png")
gato = CreaSprites(imagen_gato, None, None)
```

Si sustityo `if isinstance(color, pygame.Surface)` por
`elif isinstance(color, pygame.Surface)` el editor de código de
pycharm lo marca como erróneo.

El código que da error es:

```
        elif isinstance(color, pygame.Surface):
            self.image = color
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Y el error:
An illegal target for a variable annotation

¿Alguien sabe qué ocurre?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que marca? ¿Por qué no pones tu código con el `elif` que mencionas?

Comment: Por favor, ve a [edit] la pregunta y compártenos el error completo que indica el editor. Qué pasa si _corres_ el código?

Comment: No puedes colocar `elif` por que el docstring que colocaste rompe la estructura del `if`

Comment: Si coloco elif seguido de una instrucción deiferente a la que da el problema, este no aparece. Por ejemplo, en elif 1==1: no da el problema.

Answer (score 4):

### Una cadena no es un comentario

Aunque es fácil confundirse porque los "docstrings" son cadenas que se usan a modo de comentarios, no son lo mismo.

- Un comentario (todo lo que aparece tras un `#`) es ignorado completamente por Python, es como si no estuviera ahi, como si nunca lo hubieras escrito. En concreto **no genera nada en los bytecodes** (que son el resultado de "compilar" el programa)
- Una cadena en cambio sí que genera algo. Genera un objeto de tipo String. Ese objeto puede ser asignado a una variable, o puede ser "descartado" si no se asigna a ningún sitio.

Así que en el código siguiente:

```
print("Hola")
"Esto es una prueba"
print("Mundo")
```

la cadena que aparece entre ambos `print()` está generando un objeto String que se "pierde" por no estar asignado. No es un error de sintaxis, debido a que Python admite una expresión cualquiera en una línea, si bien si esa expresión no se asigna, se perderá. El código anterior es por ello tan válido como este otro:

```
print("Hola")
32 * 2
print("Mundo")
```

La expresión 32 * 2 genera un entero (64) que se pierde por no estar almacenado.

Debido a que estas cadenas no asignadas "se descartan" hay quien decide usarlas a modo de comentario, pero esto trae problemas:

1. No siempre se descartan por completo. Si son la primera línea de una función (o de una clase) se almacenan como parte de esa función (o clase) en un atributo llamado `__doc__`, el cual se puede usar luego para generar automáticamente documentación. Este es un uso perfectamente válido y estandarizado, al que se denomina *docstring*. No obstante la razón de ser del *docstring* es documentar la función de cara a quien vaya a usarla, especificando qué hace, qué parámetros recibe y qué resultado devuelve, y no comentar detalles internos de implementación, para lo que se debe usar el comentario normal `#`.
2. La indentación con que aparezca esa cadena **es significativa**

Y eso es lo que pasa precisamente en tu caso:

```
if a == 0:
   print("Hola")
"Esto es una prueba"
elif a ==1:
   print("Mundo")
```

Debido a que la cadena `"Esto es una prueba"` aparece al mismo nivel de indentación que el `if`, se considera una sentencia que **da por terminado el `if`**. Por tanto cuando más tarde encuentra un `elif` se produce el error.

Eso no ocurre si usas un verdadero comentario:

```
if a == 0:
   print("Hola")
# Esto es un comentario
elif a == 1:
   print("Mundo")
```

Comment: Tu explicación es magistral abulafia. Muchas gracias por esta. Ha sido realmente claro y didáctico.